# Как сделать чтобы интерфейс выглядел одинаково на любых устройствах?

Tags: android

Надо сделать чтобы кнопки нормально(по середине) отображались на любых устройствах,

Сейчас отображается вот так:

Зелёные прямоугольники это кнопки они просто пока-что без иконок и и я вставил зелёный квадрат

на 1ом телефоне вроде по середине https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsnji.png

на 2ом телефоне уже нет https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VF6m.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".ActivityV1">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:layout_width="38.0dip"
        android:layout_height="37.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="3.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="3.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/settings_white"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="109.0dip"
        android:layout_height="98.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="206.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="232.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/button_1"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="108.0dip"
        android:layout_height="105.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="104.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="125.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/button_2"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/button_3"
        android:layout_width="109.0dip"
        android:layout_height="98.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="206.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="17.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/button_3"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/4"
        android:layout_width="108.0dip"
        android:layout_height="105.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="299.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="125.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/profiler"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите разметку. Скорее всего вы там что-то не то делаете

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил в шапку

Comment: У вас принципиально неправильный подход. Указывая конкретные значения отступов не позволят реально выровнять кнопки. RelativeLayout к тому же устарел. Вам лучше переписать это на `ConstraintLayout`, указывая всем вьюхам привязки относительно друг друга и родителя. Так будет проще и работать будет как надо и везде. Ну и использование `dip` и дробных значений в ширине высоте тоже странно. Лучше как-то по содержимому размеры ставить или в `dp`, вынесенных в `dimens.xml` файл для унификации

Comment: Привет @ЮрийСПб, ConstraintLayout немного солоноват для меня, я вписал его вместо RelativeLayout и мне предложило androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout, я конечно не эксперт, но мне кажется это не то.
Можете тогда пожалуйста написать как должен выглядеть мой код с  ConstraintLayout, чтобы отображалось на любых устройствах.

Comment: `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` - это как раз то, что нужно) Написать разметку, боюсь, не смогу, т.к. на это время нужно и не вполне ясно как именно вы хотите расположить вьюхи. Попробуйте посмотреть любую статью про ConstraintLayout - там в целом не сложно. Если кратко, то, наверное, вам надо вертикальный 1-ый квадрат привязать к верху родителя и к верху одного из горизонтальных. 2-ой к низу горизонтального. Оба к началу и концу родителя. Горизонтальный первый привязать к началу и низу 1-ого вертикального, 2-ой - к концу и низу 1-ого вертикального. Примерно так